# SQL group by in Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, data-analysis

I'm trying to get monthly production using group by after converting the unix column into regular timestamp. Can you please tell how to use group by here in the code.

'''

```
With production(SystemId, dayof, monthof, yearof, powerwatts, productionwattshours) as 
(
Select   SystemId,
            [dayof] = DAY(hrdtc), 
            [monthof] = MONTH(hrdtc),
            [yearof] = YEAR(hrdtc),
        powerwatts, productionwatthours
    from (
    Select  * , dateadd(s, UnixTime, '19700101') as hrdtc from meterreading ) ds
    )

    Select * from production
    where systemId = 2368252
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this (technically you don't need a subquery but it allows you to avoid repeating the `DATEADD()` expression):

```
SELECT SystemId = 2368252,
  [Month] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(hrdtc), MONTH(hrdtc), 1),
  powerwatts = SUM(powerwatts),
  productionwatthours = SUM(productionwatthours)
FROM
(
  SELECT powerwatts, productionwatthours,
    DATEADD(SECOND, UnixTime, '19700101') as hrdtc
  FROM dbo.enphasemeterreading
  WHERE systemId = 2368252 
) AS ds 
GROUP BY DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(hrdtc), MONTH(hrdtc), 1);
```

If you want to also avoid repeating the `GROUP BY` expression:

```
SELECT SystemId = 2368252,
  [Month],
  powerwatts = SUM(powerwatts),
  productionwatthours = SUM(productionwatthours)
FROM
(
  SELECT [Month] = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(hrdtc), MONTH(hrdtc), 1),
    powerwatts, productionwatthours
  FROM
  (
    SELECT powerwatts, productionwatthours,
      DATEADD(SECOND, UnixTime, '19700101') as hrdtc
    FROM dbo.enphasemeterreading
    WHERE systemId = 2368252 
  ) AS ds1
) AS ds2 
GROUP BY [Month];
```

Personally I don't think that's any prettier or clearer. A couple of other tips:

- Spell it out; [shorthand is lazy and problematic](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- Always [qualify tables and other objects with schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Updated requirement (please state these up front): How would I join *this query* to another table?

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeOtherTable AS sot
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT SystemId = 2368252,
    [Month],
    powerwatts = SUM(powerwatts),
    productionwatthours = SUM(productionwatthours)
  FROM
  ...
  GROUP BY [Month]
) AS agg
ON sot.SystemId = agg.SystemId;
```

Comment: The reason I wanted to use CTE in my above query is so I can join it another table which has systemId as primary key.

Comment: ' Select SystemId, DeviceName, DATEADD(SECOND, LastEnergyAt, '19700101') as lastenergy , 
   DATEADD(SECOND, Lastreportat, '19700101') as lastreported,
   DATEADD(SECOND, OperationalAt, '19700101') as lastoperational from 
                Enphasesystem as ES '

Comment: Could you please tell me how to join table mentioned in above comment to my orignial query?

Comment: @GKV Well, yes, if you need to join to another query, you could put that query into a CTE or subquery and join it to the other table. This requirement wasn't in the original question.